# How to access asp.net controls from DNN skin code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm working on a DNN skin using [Christoc's DNN templates](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates) and when I create a normal ASP.NET control on my home.ascx file, I'm unable to reference it in the code behind.

I know that on normal web projects, the `aspx.designer.cs` file controls all that but I don't know how to generate one for a `.ascx` file or if that's even how it should work in a DNN skin.

**How do I reference an ASP.NET control from the code behind in a DNN skin template?**

Here's the control I'm trying to access:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlAccountSettings" runat="server">My Account</asp:HyperLink>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace Company.Modules.CompanySkin2019
{        
    public partial class Home : SkinBase
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            UserInfo currUserInfo = UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo();
            hlAccountSettings.NavigateUrl = Globals.NavigateURL(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID, "Profile", "userId=" + currUserInfo.UserID, "pageno=1"); 
            // ^ ERROR: The name 'hlAccountSettings' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we create a user control like:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="changeForAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="changeForAll_OnCheckedChanged" Text="Apply changes for all devices" Checked="True" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </label>
</div>
```

And the code behind:

```
 public partial class ChangeForAllCheckbox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            changeForAll.Checked = ...;
        }
    }

    protected void changeForAll_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```